# Create an excerpt for each element found

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I find all elements with a `<tspan>` tag, then limit each of those `<tspan>`'s to ten characters?

Ex:
This:

```
<tspan>Bla bla bla bla</tspan>
<tspan>Bla bla bla bla</tspan>
<tspan>Bla bla bla bla</tspan>
<tspan>Bla bla bla bla</tspan>
```

Should be this:

```
<tspan>Bla bla bl...</tspan>
<tspan>Bla bla bl...</tspan>
<tspan>Bla bla bl...</tspan>
<tspan>Bla bla bl...</tspan>
```

Using jQuery or Javascript that may look like this:

```
var tableExcerpt = $('tspan').text().substring(0, 10) + '...';
$('tspan').text(tableExcerpt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost made it actually. You just need to use `.each` :

```
$('tspan').each(function(){
    var tableExcerpt = $(this).text().substring(0, 10) + '...';
    $(this).text(tableExcerpt);
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a ";" to the end of your .each(). Other than that, it's perfect, thank you!

Comment: `;` is actually not needed in this case, as long as there is a linebreak: http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript

Comment: @Terry that is a great resource!